# Want a static member function to call a member variable of the same class

Tags: c++, static-methods, pointer-to-member

**headerfile.h**

```
class A
{
  cv::Mat depthimagemouse;
  std::string m_winname;

public:

  A(const std::string &winname, const cv::Mat depth_clean);
  static void onMouse( int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param );
};
```

**cppfile.cpp**

```
A::A(const std::string &winname, const cv::Mat depth_clean)
    : m_winname(winname), depthimagemouse(depth_clean)
{
//something..
}

void A::onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
{
//Here I want to use depthimagemouse member variable (and other members..)
}
```

My question is how can I use depthimagemouse variable in onMouse method?

Comment: Since `onMouse` is static, it should(i am not sure about can) not access non static members.

Comment: You want something exactly opposite than in your title: you want to access member from static method. And it's impossible.

Comment: I know! that's my question as I must declare `onMouse` as static to remove its `this` pointer

Comment: The people saying you can't access non-static members within a static method are talking nonsense. Static methods have fully privileged access to all class members of any instance, so long as they know which instance to use, through a `this` pointer/reference. Many libraries provision callbacks with 'user data' pointers that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: @underscore_d yes, you can do that, but why declare method as static then?

Comment: @MaciekGrynda e.g. if you are using a callback mechanism that does not directly support member functions, a static function is required to provide a compatible function signature. Like the OP is, here, with OpenCV, in this repeat of a previous thread in which they were already told all of this.

Comment: @MaciekGrynda I must declare it as static to remove its `this` pointer so as I can pass a pointer-to-member-function to setMouseCallback in OpenCV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be surprised if the library didn't explain this somewhere in its documentation, but anyway. This is standard procedure when you're using callbacks that don't support member functions, but you still need a way to access member data. So, you do the following:

- Pass a reference to the instance as your user data pointer `param` (or a member thereof) when registering the callback.
- Cast this back to the concrete type to access its members. A class static function has full access to all members of its class, via a provided instance.

So, you can do it this way:

```
auto &that = *static_cast<A *>(param); // <= C++03: use A &that
// Cast to const A if you want, or use a pointer, or etc.
std::cout << that.depthimagemouse << std::endl;
```

Or it's often nicer syntactically to immediately despatch to a member function and let it do everything:

```
static_cast<A *>(param)->doRestOfStuff(evt, x, y, flags);
// Include a const in the cast if the method is const
```

Or anywhere in between.

Comment: The issue is that my compiler doesn't support C++11 (it seems!)
But @Jean-Baptiste Yunès solution works fine

Comment: It says error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ ’ with no type when I use `auto`
And I didn't say that you're wrong I just use it without `auto`

Comment: @RosCpp Ohhh, sorry, I forgot about the`auto` and didn't notice it when I reviewed the post... it's just a habit that I don't even think about! Thanks for letting me know, and I've added a note about that. It's funny, actually: `auto` usually saves typing, but for this example `class A`, it makes things worse in that sense ;-) The power of habits...

Answer (score 0):

`depthimagemouse` is an instance member, means that each `A` instance (object if you prefer) has its own `depthimagemouse`. Your `onMouse` method is a static one, means that it is not related to any particular given instance but to **all** instances, and thus it's nonsense to think about accessing `depthimagemouse` without specifying which instance you are interested in.

Without any more information about `onMouse` and your model it is hard to tell you what to do. May be `param` can be used to specify an instance of `A` that the static method will receive? In that case, a cast can be used to get the instance back inside the method: `A *anInstance = static_cast<A *>(param);`  with which you can then play: `anInstance->depthimagemouse` (see that we are talking about the `depthimagemouse` of a given instance?), etc.

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot without `auto`

Answer (score 0):

make `depthimagemouse` as global variable can achieve, but need intialize it in a specialized method. here is one implementation

**global.h**

```
extern cv::Mat depthimagemouse;
```

**global.cpp**

```
cv::Mat depthimagemouse;
```

**headerfile.h**

```
#include "global.h"

class A
{
  std::string m_winname;

public:

  A(const std::string &winname);
  void init(const cv::Mat depthimagemouse_) {depthimagemouse = depthimagemouse_};
  static void onMouse( int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param );
};
```

**cppfile.cpp**

```
A::A(const std::string &winname)
: m_winname(winname)
{
//something..
}

void A::onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param )
{
  //use depthimagemouse
}
```